# Reshape logical matrix into abnormal shape

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to track a stationary point while an ROI moves around it. attached is an example of how the ROI looks and the different configurations which can occur.[image]

The ROI region is defined using the following code and the red point is a basic X,Y location.

```
exlook = 1;
OrtD = [-101 175 124];
Xdat = [303 261 152];
Ydat = [274 314 287];

Observedpoint = [280,270]; % X,Y

Xloc = 50*cosd(-OrtD(exlook)-16.5+[0:170])+Xdat(exlook);
Yloc = 50*sind(-OrtD(exlook)-16.5+[0:170])+Ydat(exlook);
Xloc = horzcat(Xloc,Xdat(exlook));
Yloc = horzcat(Yloc,Ydat(exlook));

PolymaskXYloc = poly2mask(Xloc,Yloc,450,560);
imshow(PolymaskXYloc,[0 2]); hold on;
scatter(Observedpoint(1),Observedpoint(2),'r','filled')
```

I thought about using the **inpolygon** as matlab showed it to build a logical matrix based on where a point or series of points are in the region.

```
[polin polon] = inpolygon(Xloc,Yloc,Observedpoint(1),Observedpoint(2));
```

The problem lies in that I would like to define where in the ROI the point was observed. It should be possible using **inpolygon** as the program will produce a linear logical matrix and mark a 1 where the point is located. However as the output is linear, I do not know how to convert the linear matrix back into the weirdly designed ROI.

I thought about forgetting about reshaping but from my understanding; Matlab always starts from the left and goes by column to generate the linear array. As the ROI moves, that means each array would effectively change.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

edit: just thought of it, would indexing work?

Comment: Do you just need `ind2sub`?

Comment: @Wolfie, I was actually think of that as well. I think I need ind2sub to index the region. I'm looking up know to see how a logical is indexed using this function

Comment: Is your ROI always a circular sector?

Comment: yes, it just rotates and moves around the frame